# Problem embedding MongoDB Chart on a VueJS app

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, babeljs

I try to embed a MongoDB Chart on a VueJS app but I am stuck at the very first step.

After doing npm install, I try to import the library like this:

```
import ChartsEmbedSDK from "@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom";
```

Immediately after this line is included, my VueJS app complains the following:

```
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom/dist/charts-embed-dom.esm.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (556:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
| 
|   return { ...sharedEmbedOptions,
|     chartId,
|     filter,
```

It looks like the ES6 rest operator "..." used in the charts-embed-dom module is not recognised by my babel loader? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to embed the chart as an IFRAME
as in:

```
<iframe style="background: #FFFFFF;border: none;border-radius: 2px;box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(70, 76, 79, .2);" width="640" height="480" src="https://charts.mongodb.com/charts-m220-usxbb/embed/charts?id=621dfa65-fe67-407c-8eff-xxxxxxxx&maxDataAge=3600&theme=light&autoRefresh=true"></iframe>
```

see the following for an example: https://restaurantapp-bfnrh.mongodbstitch.com/

Also please post your package.json as it might aid in investigating. Once you have the package working you also need to worry about whether the chart needs authentication to view.